# linux slave cannot checkout source , svn: E175002: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac

Tags: jenkins, svnkit, slave

environment is:
jenkins 1.5.20 on RHEL 6
jenkins SSH Slaves plugin 1.2
SSH Credentials plugin 1.3

i have a user on both the master host and slave host that can successfully ssh between the two
hosts and on the master there is no issue checking out source after using the JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3  and restarting jenkins workaround

every build on the slave throws:
svn: E175002: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac

my guess is for some reason the java process running the agent on the slave is not using the svnkit
definition and i cannot figure out how to tell jenkins to use it on the slaves... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

so, in the configuration section of the slave, i specified -Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3 in the JVM options and the build ran

rgds
Miguel